# Node Reference, and Entity Reference are great; I need “Menu reference”

Tags: routes

Is there a Menu reference module I can use to attach menus to nodes, and render them on the page?

Comment: Which thing restricts you to choose a menu from menu list? Please clear about query!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used the module, but in theory, [Block Reference](http://drupal.org/project/blockreference) should be able to solve your problem. If needed, I assume you can combine it with [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) to set up the menu blocks you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can control which pages to display blocks (menus) on. It would be quite simple only to show a specific menu in a page and region of your liking.

This is done in the block section.

Comment: Truth, but there is not a great UI for that.  This is for a customer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a [Menu Reference Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_reference)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context). Awesomeness packaged.